# select box's value after submit

Tags: php, select

I have simple code
  File name:newEmptyPHP.php

```
<form method="post" action="newEmptyPHP.php">Title:
    <select name="title">
        <option value="select">Select</option>;
        <option value="Dr" selected=<?php if(isset($_POST[ 'title'])=="Dr" ){ echo "selected"; } ?>>Dr</option>';
        <option value="Prof">Prof</option>';
        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>';
        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>';
        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>';
        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>';</select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I want to keep selected particular value which was selected before the form submission.
But i did not get the desirable output.
any help appreciated.

Comment: are you making the dropdown dynamically or statically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
<option value="Dr" selected=<?php if(isset($_POST['title']) == "Dr")
{ echo "selected";  } ?> >Dr</option>';
```

to

```
<option value="Dr" <?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Dr")
{ echo "selected='selected'";  } ?> >Dr</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<option value="Dr" selected=<?php if(isset($_POST['title']) == "Dr"){ echo "selected";  } ?> >Dr</option>';
```

To :

```
<option value="Dr" <?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Dr"){ echo 'selected="selected"';  } ?> >Dr</option>';
```

1.Remove `isset` where you are checking it for value, `isset` will return either `true` or `false` 
2.Make `selected="selected` inside `if` condition

Comment: But this is wrong :isset($_POST['title']) == "Dr", It will never be true

Comment: Sure, `isset` returns bool.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['title']) == "Dr"){ echo "selected";  } ?>
```

Change to

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Dr"){ echo "selected";  } ?>
```

But better to use JS / jQuery. Example for **jQuery**:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Dr"):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('select[name=title]').val('<?php echo html_special_chars($_POST[''title'])?>');
    });
    </script>
<?php endif?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thin you have static option values.If so the you have to check for every option like as below for one.

```
<form method="post" action="newEmptyPHP.php">
    Title:<select name="title" > 
                                <option value="select" >Select</option>; 
<?php 
     $selected = ""; 
     if(isset($_POST['title']) &&  $_POST['title'] == "Dr")
     { 
       $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
     } 
 ?>
 <option value="Dr" <?php echo $selected; ?>>Dr</option> 
 <option value="Prof">Prof</option> 
 <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
 <option value="Ms">Ms</option> 
 <option value="Miss">Miss</option> 
 <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option> 
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if($_POST['title'] == "Dr")
{ ?>
<option value="Dr" selected>Dr</option>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<?php
<option value="Dr">Dr</option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code. `isset(Something)` will return either `true` or `false` and will not return `Dr` you are looking for.

Retry with this

```
<form method="post" action="newEmptyPHP.php">
    Title:<select name="title" > 
              <option value="" >Select</option> 
              <option value="Dr" selected=<?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Dr"){ echo "selected";  } ?> >Dr</option>'; 
              <option value="Prof" <?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Prof"){ echo "selected";  } ?>>Prof</option>'; 
              <option value="Mr" <?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Mr"){ echo "selected";  } ?>>Mr</option>'; 
              <option value="Ms" <?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Ms"){ echo "selected";  } ?>>Ms</option>'; 
              <option value="Miss" <?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Miss"){ echo "selected";  } ?>>Miss</option>'; 
              <option value="Mrs" <?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Mrs"){ echo "selected";  } ?>>Mrs</option>'; 
         </select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather prefer this code for the purpose

```
$option_array = array('select'=>'select','mr'=>'mr'... other values);

<?php
  $option_string = '';
 foreach($option_array as $key=>$value)
 {
   if($key == $_POST['title'])
   {
     $selected = 'selected';
   }
   else
   {
    $selected = '';
   }
   $option_string .= "<option value='$key' $selected>$value</option>";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="newEmptyPHP.php">Title:
<select name="title">
<?php echo $option_string; ?>    
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```